# Detecting USB Serial Adapter Being Physically Disconnected

Tags: c#, .net, service

First, I want to say that I know there are versions of this point already on this site and others detailing issues w/ USB Serial Adapters and processing their physical disconnect in someone's application.  I have reviewed several of those discussions and tried the various suggestions without any success.  Maybe I am missing something but maybe I am not. At this point, I have lost track of how many and which ones I have tried and I am looking to start things over fresh from this post and not just rehash old items.

To sum up most of the original posts with the most recent one being from at least within the past year, there is has been a known problem in Windows/development handling of USB Serial Adapters that are unplugged.  Some of the posts/solutions center around an unhandled/uncatchable exception that happens when closing the serial port and a fix in .NET 4.0 that is supposed to resolve this and, I think, allow for the event/exception to be caught.

What I am doing and experiencing is this:

I have a .NET 4.0 Service application written in C# that opens a COM port and listens for data using the built-in SerialPort class.  This data is then reported possibly to other local applications or remotely to other locations.  I am testing using a Tripp Lite USB to Serial Port adapter but the actual report of a problem was from someone using a laptop that has an internal USB to Serial Port adapter device that will from time to time "disconnect" and "reconnect" from/to the Windows OS.  I am simulating the problem w/ my device by physically disconnecting the USB device while the port is open in my Windows Service application.

What I am seeing in my testing/debugging is that there is no reaction to the disconnection or reconnection of the USB device.  I am receiving data and that flow of data just stops to the Service application.  If I reconnect the device, the COM port is still open to the application but there is no new data.  If I close the port, there is no "application blow up" / UnhandledException error.  The port closes and the application stops normally.  At no point in time, do I receive a catchable exception which is what I would like to see happen.  If I start the application, data starts to flow again.

I want the application to know when the USB Serial/COM port is removed from the system preferably with some kind of exception at the SerialPort level that would allow me to catch the exception, close the port, and go into "reopen port mode" until the device is "reconnected" to the PC.  Is this going to be possible in this manner around the SerialPort class or do I need to pursue a solution centered around the generic "USB Device" being disconnected rather than the "Serial Port" being disconnected?  (I have my application programmatically determining that the device is an USB device already rather than having to flag it as such in preparation for the latter...............)

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Something that I have since discovered:  With the USB Serial adapter disconnected and I stop the Service application, the SerialPort.IsOpen value is set to false so something is detecting the disconnect and marking the serial port closed (is that the .NET 4.0 fix??).  However, I have not determined anyway to catch when the IsOpen flag change takes place.  I have an override of Close() in place and it is not getting called at disconnect time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the device that you are communicating with over serial?  Does it have any support for sending a handshake/status request? If so, could you intermittently poll it to check that the device is still there, and if nothing comes back after a timeout, raise the exception yourself?

Alternatively, I have used this [library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21503/Hardware-Helper-Library-for-C) once before, which allows you to interact with the Windows Device Manager.  The article provides some detail about how to extend the class to monitor for device changes, you could implement this and with a bit of luck have an event raised at the moment that the device briefly disconnects - you could use this to to test your device rather than continual polling, possible?